# Analytical methods to solve a cubic equation

Tags: problem-solving

I'm having trouble solving this cubic equation: $x^3 - 7x^2 -27x+64=0$

I was able to prove that it has no rational roots, and by graphing the cubic function, I found that its 3 roots are all real, being irrational.

Is there any analytical method of obtaining these irrational roots without resorting to the cubic formula?

Comment: See, e.g. [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_formula#General_formula_for_roots).

Comment: The trigonometric method will work. Not pleasant.